# How do you set up Salesforce SOS?

Tags: appexchange

I'm trying to set up SOS for my organization but I'm getting the error when trying to install the app exchange package found in the tutorial [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sos.meta/sos/getting_started-index.htm)

When I try to install it, I get this error here.
**1. (SOSSession.SOS_Reference_Id__c) Entity not available The Entity 'SOSSession' is not found. Contact the vendor for more details.**

I have a service cloud license and the steps in the instructions are not clear.

Comment: Did anyone ever get this figured out? I'm trying to get this setup in a Dev org and keep getting the SOS error. I don't seem to have any SOS "Stuff" in setup and can't figure out how to enable it in a Dev org... This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
(SOSSession.SOS_Reference_Id__c) Entity not available The Entity 'SOSSession' is not found. Contact the vendor for more details.

Answer (score 0):

They have added this field in the latest version, try to get the latest (SOS 196) from https://salesforcesos.com/#sc-details

Comment: The error indicates that the actual SObject itself doesn't exist. I'm not clear on the details but I think that there may be a license for SOS that the user does not have.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup Service Cloud using [Setting up SOS in Service Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sos.meta/sos/getting_started-setting_up_service_cloud.htm)

This should provide you with:

OrganizationID: 0000000xxxx

DeployementID :000000xxxx

SOS Access URL: https://x.xx.com/sosagentxxx/

Once that is setup you can follow the instructions for setup of [iOS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sos.meta/sos/getting_started_ios-index.htm) or [Android](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sos.meta/sos/getting_started_android-index.htm)

Use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), for downloading and managing Repo.

Pod Instructions:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/goinstant/pods-specs-public'
pod 'SOS'
```

Hope that helps.